# Wowza Transcoder parallel encoding

Tags: parallel-processing, mp4, wowza

We are using Wowza and HDFVR for capturing webcam video and transcoding that video into mp4.

We have noticed that if multiple users record videos in the same time, the flash files are saved on the server, but only one mp4 record has been generated. It seems transcoder is available only for the first user.

Is this feature by design or there are configurations that will allow Wowza to transcode multiple flv files into mp4 format?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, i guess you should use different stream names, and that's it!
Wowza supports parallel processing/transcoding/recording/publishing/playback for sure

Answer (score 0):

Recording is usually based on stream name and different sessions (at different times) with same stream name are usually differentiated by Wowza by adding a number to the video file name.

Same stream name can be used simultaneously by multiple broadcasters. Only 1 broadcaster will use that stream name and rest of simultaneous publishing will fail.

Make sure your app/solution does not use same stream name (usually username is used as stream name by most apps) so different users can stream at same time.

For converting videos to other formats you can also use FFMPEG.